# Appium Unable to locate elements in mobile app using text in UIAutomator

Tags: selenium, xpath, appium, android-uiautomator, invalidselectorexception

When I try to use text in XPath, I am getting the error

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Argument was an invalid selector (e.g. XPath/CSS). (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"
```

This is the code that i am trying to find an element

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@text=‘Enter recipient. Editing.’]")).sendKeys("8659741253");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is with the text editor. " ‘ " character is not the expected single quote . So use the normal " ' ". 
Hope this will work.

Answer (score 2):

To send the text `8659741253` to the `WebElement` you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(normalize-space(),'Enter recipient. Editing.')]")).sendKeys("8659741253");
```